# How to save panda data frame as CSV in MinIO.?

Tags: python, pandas, minio

I am new in MinIo and i am using minio python library and trying to save panda data frame as CSV.
as per there documentation, I am using [put_object](https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-api-reference.html#put_object) to insert the data in remote cloud location. below is my code.

```
from minio import Minio
from minio.error import ResponseError
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
import pandas as pd
import os
minioClient = Minio('mydomain.com',
              access_key='my_access_key',
              secret_key='scret_key',
              secure=False)
df = panda data frame
csv_buffer = StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
minioClient.put_object('mu_bucket',
                       'mypath/test.csv',
                        data = csv_buffer.getvalue(),
                        length = csv_buffer.tell(),
                        content_type='application/csv')
```

in there documention all example are saving physical file but i need to save from dataframe.
thats why i am using StringIO to create a string buffer. but getting the below error.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read
```

Any help is greatly appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO`. `BytesIO` allows you to wrap byte arrays up in a stream which you can give to minio.

```py
from io import BytesIO

import pandas as pd
from minio import Minio

minioClient = Minio('mydomain.com',
              access_key='my_access_key',
              secret_key='secret_key',
              secure=False)

df = pd.DataFrame()
csv_bytes = df.to_csv().encode('utf-8')
csv_buffer = BytesIO(csv_bytes)

minioClient.put_object('mu_bucket',
                       'mypath/test.csv',
                        data=csv_buffer,
                        length=len(csv_bytes),
                        content_type='application/csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
from minio import Minio

def upload_to_minio(access_key, secret_key, endpoint, bucket_name, local_file_path, object_name):
   

    """
    Uploads a file to a Minio bucket from a local system.

    Args:
        access_key (str): Minio access key.
        secret_key (str): Minio secret key.
        server_url (str): Minio server link
        bucket_name (str): Name of th bucket.
        local_file_path (str): Local file path.
        object_name (str): Object name in the Minio bucket.

    """
    try:
        # Initialize Minio client
        minio_client = Minio(endpoint,
                             access_key=access_key,
                             secret_key=secret_key,
                             secure=False)  # Set to True if using HTTPS

        # Create the bucket if it doesn't exist
        if not minio_client.bucket_exists(bucket_name):
            minio_client.make_bucket(bucket_name)
            print(f"Bucket '{bucket_name}' created successfully.")

        # Upload file to Minio
        minio_client.fput_object(bucket_name, object_name,local_file_path)

    except ResponseError as err:
        print(f"Minio error occurred: {err}")


    except Exception as err:
        print(f"other error occurred: {err}")
```